# How does this C function work?

Tags: c, function, linked-list, nodes

I was reading 'Learn C The Hard Way'. Here a function List `*List_create()` has a return type List which I understand but I don't get it  how `*List_create()` really works? What kind of function is this ?

```
 struct ListNode; //I also don't know what this does

 typedef struct ListNode{
      struct ListNode * next;
      struct ListNode * prev;
      void *value;
 }ListNode;

 typedef struct List{
      int count;
      ListNode *first;
      ListNode *last;
 }List;

 List *List_create()
 {
    return calloc(1,sizeof(List));
 }
```

Comment: do you know what calloc does

Comment: @amdixon Yes. I not asking what the function does  but how the function name works.

Comment: Careful with your return types there. Despite the placement of the * making it look like it's attached to `List_create()` what it's actually saying is that this function returns a *pointer* to a list not a list.

Comment: You do not have a function `*List_create() ` here which returns `List` (an object of struct type). You have a function `List_create() ` which returns `List *` (a pointer to a structure allocated *somewhere* on a heap).

Comment: @CiaPan Thank you. Now i get it  :)

Answer (score 0):

The function creates an instance of an object of type `List` in the dynamic memory initializes all members of the object with zeroes and returns pointer to the object.

In fact there is no need to create a list in the dynamic memory.
You can also write

```
List list = { 0 };
```

The difference is that in the first case you will need to delete the dynamically allocated list when it will not be needed any more.

In the second case it is the compiler that will bother to delete the list object.

However in the both cases you have to delete nodes of the list yourself. So you need to write a function that will free all allocated memory for allocated nodes in the list.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the out .  why doesn't this function work without the pointer in the function?

Comment: @joker pointers are fundamentally different from the objects they point to. They are an essential part of the type system in C. You cannot expect functions to work if you e.g. remove all if-statements either. `calloc` returns a pointer to memory. You can't just make it return something else ?

Comment: @joker You're wrong, the function actually has a pointer — `calloc` returns a pointer, and that pointer is in turn `return`-ed by `List_create()`. Of course one might create an intermediate variable to temporarily store the pointer—something like `List* ptr = calloc(1,sizeof(List)); return ptr;` —but that's not necessary here, you can return the value directly.

Comment: @joker See my updated post. In fact you need not to allocate dynamically the list.

Comment: @MortenJensen Than You .I should have read about calloc more :D

Answer (score 0):

`List_create` allocates memory for the List struct for a doubly linked list and initializes that struct. The struct will need to have null pointers for first and last and 0 for count. This function abuses the fact that a null pointer is the value 0 on most platforms. And `calloc` just happens to set the memory it allocates to 0.

Comment: This is C; there are no "classes".

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, there's at least one basic mistake in this code, which makes me wonder if this is a good learning source.

The return type is `List*`, not `List`. That's a pointer to the List type, which means it will live until you free it (by calling `free`). calloc allocates such memory and sets it to all zeros, which is a common way to initialize structs.

The mistake in the code is in the function declarator, `List_create()` is not a proper in modern C, it should be `List_create(void)`. Maybe it's just a typo, or maybe the author is more used to C++ where it would be ok, but it's a mistake nonetheless.

The reason the `*` is put next to the function name instead of next to `List` is that when you declare pointer variable, a `*` attaches to the name, not to the type.

E.g. `List *foo, bar;` declares two variables. `foo` is a pointer to `List` while `bar` is not a pointer. This would not be as clear if it was written `List* foo, bar;` (meaning is the same but it's confusing for someone reading the code).

Comment: I don't agree with any of your critique. The `(void)`-part has been obsoleted since C99 according to wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Void_type#cite_note-3 . It's very common to allocate objects on the heap in C, i.e. via pointers.

Comment: Do you have a source for claiming that List_create() is not *proper* C. I've never come across this.

Comment: Ok, I should've said modern C perhaps. The link @MortenJensen gave is a source. What it says is that using `f()` is obsoleted. Specifically C99 section 6.11.6 says `The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.`

Answer (score 0):

In C there are two ways to work with structs:

1. By *value*, in which there are no pointers. In this case passing the struct to a function, or returning one from a function, requires that the entire struct is copied, byte for byte. This is appropriate for small structs, but inefficient for large ones.
2. By *reference*, in which you use `malloc` or `calloc` to "dynamically" allocate a chunk of memory that will hold the struct data, and then pass the pointer around.

Your List_create function chooses to use the *by reference* model. This is probably the *correct* choice here because it ensures that updates to the list will always be visible to all holders of the pointer.

If it had chosen the *by value* model, then you would always have to ensure that you had the most recent updates in your local copy of the List struct. I.e. `List_add` would have to pass back the modified list, which would be inconvenient and bug-prone.

Example: *by reference*:

```
List *List_create()
{
    return calloc(1,sizeof(List));
}

void List_add(List* list, void *value) {
    /* TODO: actual insert code */
}

void example_caller() {
    List *list = List_create();
    List_add(list, whatever);
}
```

Example: *by value*:

```
List List_create()
{
    List result = {0};
    return result;
}

List List_add(List list, void *value) {
    /* TODO: actual insert code */
    return list;
}

void example_caller() {
    List list = List_create();
    list = List_add(list, whatever);
}
```